# For a $\sigma$-finite measure $\mu$, show that for $f$<$\infty$, non negative and measurable, $f\cdot \mu$ is $\sigma$-finite

Tags: measure-theory

Let ($\Omega,A,\mu$) be the $\sigma$-finite measure space in question.
If $B_1\subset B_2\subset B_3\dots$ is a nested sequence so that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}$$B_n$=$\Omega$ and $\mu(B_n)<\infty$.
My attempt has been the following:  $\phi_n\nearrow f$, with $\phi_n$ simple functions. Now on each set $B_n$,$\phi_n$ is bounded by some $M$>0. So $\int_{B_n}\phi_n d\mu$<$M\cdot \mu(B_n)$<$\infty$.
I was not able to prove this for measurable, non negative functions in general yet.
, because I do not know how the claim of boundedness on specific sets would translate to $f$.

Comment: By monotone convergence, you can pass to the limit. This won't destroy the bounds $M$ since you know $f$ is bounded, so you can actually replace those $M$ by bounds $M'$ of $f$. Then $\phi_n$ is also bounded by $M'$ because $\phi_n \leq f \leq M'$. Notice all bounds should actually be indexed by $n$.

Comment: @mattecapu I am not sure if $f$ is actually bounded, just because it is less than $\infty$. For example $f$=1/x for x>0 and $f$=0 elsewhere is not bounded on [0,1], when we consider the standard  real measure space.

Comment: Oh I didn't notice you didn't assume $f$ bounded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mixed up indices when you wrote the inequality:
$$
\int_{B_n} \phi_n \mathrm d\mu < M \mu(B_n)
$$
You should use two different set of indices, one for the sequence $\phi_n$ and one for the sequence $B_n$. Let's use $m$ for the latter, then we have:
$$
\int_{B_m} \phi_n \mathrm d\mu < M \mu(B_m)
$$
Now, since $f$ can be unbounded on $B_m$, we must get clever. We have to slice up $B_m$ in a sequence $B_m^k$ of sets defined as
$$
B_m^k = f^{-1}([0, k)) \cap B_m = \{f < k\} \cap B_m
$$
And the bundle them up again like so
$$
B'_k = \bigcup_{\ell,m \leq k} B_m^\ell
$$
Notice that $B_k'$ still exhibits $\mu$ as a $\sigma$-finite measure but now $f$ is bounded on $B_k'$.

Now set $M_k = \sup_{B_k'} f$ and finish up by passing
$$
\int_{B_k'} \phi_n \mathrm d\mu < M_k \mu(B_k')
$$
through the monotone convergence theorem, so you can bring the limit for $n \to \infty$ (notice: $n$, not $k$) inside the integral.

Comment: If I understood your point correctly, you basically shoved the unbounded points to k$\nearrow \infty$. That is very nice.

Comment: Yeah, kind of. There are no unbounded points but there are sets on which $$f$$ is unbounded. Then you can solve the problem with that trick of partitioning such sets in subsets where $$f$$ is bounded.